# How to arrange subtitles under a title in Yii2

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to arrange some subtitles under a main tile but it is repeating the title.

```
<div id="downloads" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel"> 
    <?php 
    $product_id = $model->id;
    $downloads_model = Printingmachinedownloads::find()->where(['productid'=>$product_id])->all();
    foreach ($downloads_model as $doc) {
        $doc_type = $doc['type'];
        $doc_label = $doc['documentlabel'];
        $doc_title  = $doc['documentname'];
        ?>
        <div class="amazingcarousel-container-1 tab_style">
            <h3><?php echo $doc_type;?></h3>
            <a target = '_blank' href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl?>images/printingmachine/downloads/<?php echo $doc_title; ?>">
                <?php echo $doc_label ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        // $doc_title = $downloads_model[0]->documentlabel;
        ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The output is:

[image: Current O/P]

What I need is

```
Brochures
 abc
 def
 ghi


Specificationsheet
xyz
lmn
opq
```

Can Anyone tell me what I have to do?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have issue with new MySQL version group by concept, you can use something like:

```
... 
$downloads_model = Printingmachinedownloads::find()->where(['productid'=>$product_id])->groupBy(['type'])->all();

foreach($downloads_model as $doc):
  <div class="amazingcarousel-container-1 tab_style">
   <h3><?= type['type'] ?></h3>
   $subtitles = Printingmachinedownloads::find()->where(['productid'=>$product_id, 'type' => $doc['type'] )->all();
   foreach($subtitles as $subtitle):
    <a target = '_blank' href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl?>images/printingmachine/downloads/<?php echo $subtitle['documentname']; ?>"> 
     <?php echo $subtitle['documentlabel'] ?>
    </a>
 enforeach;
 </div>
endforeach;
...
```

If have issue with group by you can use little non standard way, it's not best practice and effective way:

```
$downloads_model = Printingmachinedownloads::find()->where(['productid'=>$product_id])->orderBy(['type'=>SORT_DESC])->all();

$previous_title = ''; $iteration = 1;
foreach($downloads_model as $doc):
 $subtitles = Printingmachinedownloads::find()->where(['productid'=>$product_id, 'type' => $doc['type'] )->all();
 $count = count($subtitles);

 $previous_title = $previous_title ?: $doc['type'];

 if( $previous_title == $doc['type'] && $count == $iteration ):

      <div class="amazingcarousel-container-1 tab_style">
       <h3><?= $previous_title ?></h3>
       foreach($subtitles as $subtitle):
        <a target = '_blank' href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl?>images/printingmachine/downloads/<?php echo $subtitle['documentname']; ?>"> 
         <?php echo $subtitle['documentlabel'] ?>
        </a>
     enforeach;
     </div>

  $previous_title = ''; $iteration = 1;
 else:
  $iteration++;
 endif;
endforeach;
```

I didn't test it, but something similar should work.
But my suggestion and effective way will be you use relational tables 1 title container another related table containing sub titles.